# Extending the size of the video shot on iPhone

Tags: video, video-editor, aspect, iphone

I took a video in an upright (portrait) position on my iPhone. When I watch it on a computer, the edges look black. How can I remove this blackness and display it on the wide frame? I just can not do it in iMovie. I'm not talking about rotating the video.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the screen *is* showing the whole frame. That is all that your camera recorded. It did not record anything to the left or right of what you see.

On YouTube, where many people shoot their videos in a vertical format as you did, it is common to enlarge the video to the full frame width - which will cut off the top and bottom of the video - and use that as a background image. Then place your regular-size vertical video over the top of it. I used iMovie in the past and I *think* its picture-in-picture feature could accomplish this, but I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has already been mentioned above however scaling the video in the background roughly (300%) and adding a gaussian blur (soft) is common practice to achieve said effect.

Comment: Excellent specifics!  Upvote.